# Chrome: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET only for google.com

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I am in a network behind a proxy here. Whenever I try to access any of the google- sites, Chrome gives me the famous `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` error.

Chrome works for any other site I tried, no matter if HTTP or HTTPS, and the proxy does not do SSL- interception (all certificates are the original when viewed in the browser).

The google sites do work in IE and Edge on this PC, so this is not an DNS issue.

Does anyone have a clue, what to check to get this thing work?
Of course I searched this site and tried to google (with IE as Chrome does not work), but I could not really find a clue how to fix this, as it is only for this single domain...

Ah, forgot:

Windows 10, Chrome 51.0.2704.84.